# Custom Tkinter Menu Placement

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been making a game in tkinter to practice my coding skills for future projects however I've come across a stumbling block. I've been reading up on the Tkinter menus and I can't seem to find a way to place them anywhere other than the top of the window. What I am trying to do is to make a drop down selection box that allows you to pick an option and perform a command based on that option but I want it to be placed beside a label in the grid position column=2 row=2. I would like to know if this is possible or not and if not what is another way to do a similar thing.

```
import tkinter
import threading
import time
import math
from random import randrange

global Stage
Stage = 0
global Coins
Coins = 0
global Actions
Actions = 0
global ActionSpeed
ActionSpeed = 0
global Day
Day = 1
global Metal
Metal = "None"
global Type
Type = "None"
global FormLevel
FormLevel = 0
global Hardness
Hardness = 0
global Sharpness
Sharpness = 0
global Copper
Copper = 0
global Iron
Iron = 0


class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialise()

    def initialise(self):

        self.grid()
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.StartUp()

    def StartUp(self):

        #Story Section 1
        self.labelVariableStory1 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory1, anchor = 'w')
        Story1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory1.set("A great fire burned through the land two days ago.")

        self.labelVariableStory2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory2, anchor = 'w')
        Story2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory2.set("It killed hundreds and left more homeless.")

        self.labelVariableStory3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory3, anchor = 'w')
        Story3.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory3.set("Now you walk the streets begging for money just to get by.")

        self.labelVariableStory4 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory4, anchor = 'w')
        Story4.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory4.set("This is the start of your journey.")


        Story1.after(15000, lambda: Story1.destroy())
        Story2.after(15000, lambda: Story2.destroy())
        Story3.after(15000, lambda: Story3.destroy())
        Story4.after(15000, lambda: Story4.destroy())
        self.after(15000, lambda: self.New_Day())

    def New_Day(self):
        global Coins
        global Actions
        global ActionSpeed
        global Copper
        global Iron
        Actions = 5 + ActionSpeed

        #Basic Information Labels
        self.labelVariableInfo1 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo1, anchor = 'e')
        Info1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo1.set("Coins:")

        self.labelVariableInfo2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo2, anchor = 'w')
        Info2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo2.set(Coins)

        self.labelVariableInfo3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo3, anchor = 'e')
        Info3.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo3.set("Actions:")

        self.labelVariableInfo4 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo4, anchor = 'w')
        Info4.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo4.set(Actions)

        self.labelVariableInfo5 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info5 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo5, anchor = 'e')
        Info5.grid(column=12, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo5.set("Day")

        self.labelVariableInfo6 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Info6 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableInfo6, anchor = 'w')
        Info6.grid(column=13, row=0, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableInfo6.set(Day)

        if Stage == 0:

            LabelClear = tkinter.Label(self)
            LabelClear.grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=10, sticky='EW')

            WorkButton1 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Beg", command=self.Beg)
            WorkButton1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='NESW')

            SleepButton = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Sleep", command=self.Sleep)
            SleepButton.grid(column=2, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='NESW')

        if Stage >= 1:

            #Border Section
            self.labelVariableCutOff = tkinter.StringVar()
            CutOff = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableCutOff)
            CutOff.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=14, sticky='NESW')
            self.labelVariableCutOff.set("+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+")

            self.labelVariableBorder = tkinter.StringVar()
            Border1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
            self.labelVariableBorder.set(" | ")

            Border2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border2.grid(column=13, row=2, sticky='E')

            Border3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border3.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='W')

            Border4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border4.grid(column=13, row=3, sticky='E')

            Border5 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border5.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='W')

            Border6 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border6.grid(column=13, row=4, sticky='E')

            Border7 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border7.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')

            Border8 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border8.grid(column=13, row=5, sticky='E')

            Border9 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border9.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')

            Border10 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border10.grid(column=13, row=6, sticky='E')

            Border11 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border11.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='W')

            Border12 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border12.grid(column=13, row=7, sticky='E')

            Border13 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border13.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky='W')

            Border14 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border14.grid(column=13, row=8, sticky='E')

            CutOff2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableCutOff)
            CutOff2.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=14, sticky='NESW')

            Border15 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border15.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='W')

            Border16 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border16.grid(column=13, row=10, sticky='E')

            Border17 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border17.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='W')

            Border18 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border18.grid(column=13, row=11, sticky='E')

            Border19 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border19.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky='W')

            Border20 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border20.grid(column=13, row=12, sticky='E')

            Border21 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border21.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky='W')

            Border22 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border22.grid(column=13, row=13, sticky='E')

            Border23 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border23.grid(column=0, row=14, sticky='W')

            Border24 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border24.grid(column=13, row=14, sticky='E')

            Border25 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border25.grid(column=7, row=2, sticky='E')

            Border26 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border26.grid(column=7, row=3, sticky='E')

            Border27 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border27.grid(column=7, row=4, sticky='E')

            Border27 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border27.grid(column=7, row=5, sticky='E')

            Border28 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border28.grid(column=7, row=6, sticky='E')

            Border29 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border29.grid(column=7, row=7, sticky='E')

            Border30 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border30.grid(column=7, row=8, sticky='E')

            Border31 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border31.grid(column=7, row=10, sticky='E')

            Border32 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border32.grid(column=7, row=11, sticky='E')

            Border33 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border33.grid(column=7, row=12, sticky='E')

            Border34 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border34.grid(column=7, row=13, sticky='E')

            Border35 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableBorder)
            Border35.grid(column=7, row=14, sticky='E')

            CutOff3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableCutOff)
            CutOff3.grid(column=0, row=15, columnspan=14, sticky='NESW')

            #Advanced Information Labels (Functional but not Fully Implemented)
            self.labelVariableWork1 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork1, anchor='e', fg='black')
            Work1.grid(column=9, row=3, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork1.set("Metal:")

            self.labelVariableWork2 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork2, anchor='w', fg='black')
            Work2.grid(column=12, row=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork2.set(Metal)

            self.labelVariableWork3 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork3, anchor='e', fg='black')
            Work3.grid(column=9, row=4, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork3.set("Type:")

            self.labelVariableWork4 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork4, anchor='w', fg='black')
            Work4.grid(column=12, row=4, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork4.set(Type)

            self.labelVariableWork5 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work5 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork5, anchor='e', fg='black')
            Work5.grid(column=9, row=5, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork5.set("Forming:")

            self.labelVariableWork6 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work6 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork6, anchor='w', fg='black')
            Work6.grid(column=12, row=5, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork6.set("{0}%".format(FormLevel))

            self.labelVariableWork7 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work7 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork7, anchor='e', fg='black')
            Work7.grid(column=9, row=6, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork7.set("Hardening:")

            self.labelVariableWork8 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work8 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork8, anchor='w', fg='black')
            Work8.grid(column=12, row=6, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork8.set("{0}%".format(Hardness))

            self.labelVariableWork9 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work9 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork9, anchor='e', fg='black')
            Work9.grid(column=9, row=7, columnspan=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork9.set("Sharpening:")

            self.labelVariableWork10 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Work10 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableWork10, anchor='w', fg='black')
            Work10.grid(column=12, row=7, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableWork10.set("{0}%".format(Sharpness))

            #Label that is meant to be next to the menu
            Label1 = tkinter.Label(self, text="Buy:", anchor='e')
            Label1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='EW')

            #The Latest version of my unworking menu code
            '''BuyMenu = tkinter.Menu()
            Menu1 = tkinter.MenuButton(menu=BuyMenu)
            BuyMenu.add_cascade(label="Choose Metal", menu=BuyMenu)
            BuyMenu.add_command(label="Copper C: 15", command=self.BuyCopper)
            BuyMenu.add_command(label="Iron C: 25", command=self.BuyIron)
            Menu1.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky='EW')'''

            #Resource Information
            Info7 = tkinter.Label(self, text="Copper:", anchor='e')
            Info7.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='EW')

            self.labelVariableResource1 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Resource1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableResource1, anchor='w')
            Resource1.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableResource1.set(Copper)

            Info8 = tkinter.Label(self, text="Iron:", anchor='e')
            Info8.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky='EW')

            self.labelVariableResource2 = tkinter.StringVar()
            Resource1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableResource2, anchor='w')
            Resource1.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='EW')
            self.labelVariableResource2.set(Iron)



    #Stage 0 Commands
    def Beg(self):
        global Actions
        global Coins

        if Actions != 0:
            Actions -= 1
            Coins += 1
            Bonus = randrange(1,6)
            if Bonus == 5:
                Coins +=1
            self.labelVariableInfo2.set(Coins)
            self.labelVariableInfo4.set(Actions)

    def Sleep(self):

        global Day
        global Coins

        Day += 1

        if Stage == 0:
            Coins -= 2
            DarkLabel = tkinter.Label(self, bg='black')
            DarkLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=14, rowspan=2, sticky='NESW')
            self.after(5000, lambda: DarkLabel.destroy())
        if Day == 5:
            self.after(5000, lambda: self.Story1())
            Coins += 50
        else:
            self.after(5000, lambda: self.New_Day())


    #Story Section 2
    def Story1(self):

        global Stage

        self.labelVariableInfo5.set("")
        self.labelVariableInfo6.set("")

        self.labelVariableStory1 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story1 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory1, anchor = 'w')
        Story1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory1.set("On the fifth day an old man comes up to you.")

        self.labelVariableStory2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story2 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory2, anchor = 'w')
        Story2.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='NESW')
        self.labelVariableStory2.set("'It pains me to see a young person in need.'")

        self.labelVariableStory3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory3, anchor = 'w')
        Story3.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=4, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory3.set("'I'm almost at the end of my days and I have no children.'")

        self.labelVariableStory4 = tkinter.StringVar()
        Story4 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableStory4, anchor = 'w')
        Story4.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=4, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableStory4.set("'I will teach you all I can and leave you my forge.'")


        Story1.after(15000, lambda: Story1.destroy())
        Story2.after(15000, lambda: Story2.destroy())
        Story3.after(15000, lambda: Story3.destroy())
        Story4.after(15000, lambda: Story4.destroy())

        Stage += 1
        self.after(15000, lambda: self.New_Day())

    #Stage 1 Commands (These are to be triggered by the menu)
    def BuyCopper(self):
        global Coins
        global Copper
        if Coins >= 15:
            Coins -= 15
            Copper += 1
            self.labelVariableInfo2.set(Coins)
            self.labelVariableResource1.set(Copper)

    def BuyIron(self):
        global Coins
        global Iron
        if Coins >= 25:
            Coins -= 25
            Iron += 1
            self.labelVariableInfo2.set(Coins)
            self.labelVariableResource2.set(Iron)







#GUI loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Smithy')
    app.mainloop()
```

I have now included my whole code with the exception of commenting out my unworking menu code.

Comment: Did you try to use the grid method to place the widgets ? If yes, can you show the piece of code using it ?

Comment: do you want my attempts at a menu or the other widgets? Because I have alot of other widgets.

Comment: Until I get a response I'm going to just add the bits near the area I want the menu placed in

Comment: Please add enough code so that the program will run and we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I'm afraid.  We need to see just enough of your code to see what you're trying to do that doesn't work.  Please look at this post on how to crete a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have no idea how to actually do this. I'm very new to coding with anything and I don't know how to shrink my code without changing the appearance of what I want to have happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an [option menu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) or a [ComboBox](http://www.tkdocs.com/widgets/combobox.html). They are menus but on the page not at the top of the screen.

Here is the code to add options to the OptionMenu:

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
def change(value):
    options.append("YOUR_OPTION_HERE")
    menu=drop["menu"]
    menu.delete("0", END)
    for string in options:
        menu.add_command(label=string, command=lambda value=string: var.set(value))

options=["hello", "goodbye", "welcome"]
var=StringVar()
drop=OptionMenu(root, var, *options, command=change)
drop.config(width=15)
drop.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you just what I needed, however I would like to know how to add on to this with more variables in a later stage. For example if at one point I wanted two options but after doing something I add two more, how would I go about doing that?